# Azure Devops access without vscode subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a user that I want to give access to my Azure DevOps repository (he doesnt have a Visual Studio subscription), how can I achieve that.

I have tried to give Basic and Stakeholder access on the **Organization Settings /Users** but it didnt worked.

I then tried to add him to a team on the **project settings** and gave contributor permission to the team, I then gave permission of the repository to the team but It still doesnt work.